# persistence.xml - spring JPA

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, jpa

I have read dozens of articles, but I cant figure out, where the mistake is... it should be really simple. I'm trying to write app on appengine using Spring and JPA.

I am using JEE5 project (dont know if it matters)

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation">
        <value>classpath*:/META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="transactions-optional" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

The persistence.xml file is located in META-INF directory (ROOT/META-INF/persistence.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
        <provider>org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jpa.DatastorePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

I still get this exception (i was trying to move meta-inf directory in src directory with no success, the exception was the same)

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'genericJpaDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory cz.cvut.fel.pupilbook.dao.support.jpa.GenericJpaDAO.entityManagerfactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named transactions-optional
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:844)
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is `META-INF/persistence.xml` in your compilation output (where your compiled classes settle)? If no, then have you tried to place `META-INF/persistence.xml` there manually and see if the issue persists?

Comment: yep, its in target/name_of_the_project/META-INF folder, when I build it, also in project.war/META-INF

Comment: Actually I ment the place where your classes go, that is, where your folders `cz/cvut/fel/pupilbook/.../OneOfYourClasses.class` are placed. So, `META-INF` should go next to `cz` folder with compiled classes. If this doesn't work however, then I'm as confused as you are...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anwer consists of two parts.

1. denisk was correct about the location of persistence.xml, it should be under src.
2. I was missing some dependencies to datanucleus (I thought they are provided). After adding them I got plenty of relevant exceptions. After resolving them everything works.

So - it was coincidence of two problem, each of them masked part of the other.

Comment: can you please post complete solution. I mean what do you changed after that it works fine.

Comment: sorry, this answer is more than 2 years old and I dont have the sources available :-(